# Controlling 110v swamp cooler(Mastercool) using Nest thermostat

Tags: thermostat

Afer hearing many great things about Nest Thermostat, I decided to buy the 3rd Generation Nest thermostat. But after doing much research, I came to know that my MasterCool Swamp Cooler will not work with Nest, but there is some hope.

I came to know that there is a way to convert my MasterCool to work with Nest.

I read the post [Controlling 110v swamp cooler using Nest thermostat](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/84680/controlling-110v-swamp-cooler-using-nest-thermostat)

but I am confused as what model works the best and at its optimal level.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thank you,