# Anyone connect the MasterStat Model 110423-2 three lines to Google Nest thermostat?

Tags: thermostat, nest, evaporative-cooling

I have read the poster here:

[Controlling 110v swamp cooler using Nest thermostat](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/84680/controlling-110v-swamp-cooler-using-nest-thermostat)

about how to control the swamp cooler using the nest. However, I don't have reputation to post comments to that post yet. So I am asking a new question.

Currently, I have the Masterstat:

http://pdf.lowes.com/useandcareguides/009009474287_use.pdf

The model can also buy from amazon:

[https://www.amazon.com/MasterStat-Thermostat-for-Evaporative-Coolers/dp/B00CORM70S](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00CORM70S)

It has a big box with the Mastercool swamp cooler and then three lines coming out from the control board to the wall mounted control unit:

1: Fan Lo - Red wire
2: Pump - Black wire
3: Fan Hi - Black wire

I am wondering whether the 1 and 3 can connect to the Y1 or Y2 but not sure how to connect the pump.